# accessing href attribute with classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to access the href attribute with jquery using the class name. How can I do that below is the code.

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="class-name">Hyper Link</a>
```

I only want to access it with the class-name since I have many links and want to use the classname to access the href link.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want - but the href of your link should probably be made into an absolute rather than relative link...

```
    $('a.class-name').each(function(){
        alert( this.href ) // alerts http://currentdomain.com/www.google.com
        alert( $(this).attr('href') ) // alerts www.google.com
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('a.class-name').each(function(){
     this.href //do something with href
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$('a.class-name')` with a dash instead of camel-hump?

Comment: @maerics, yes true, sorry im used to coding a certain way and its hard to break the habit

Answer (score 2):

Presuming (1) that you are using jQuery 1.6 and (2) that your link is the only one that has that class:

```
var linkHref = $('a.class-name').prop('href');
```

If you are using jQuery 1.5 or older, you'll have to use `attr` rather than `prop`. If you have more than one element with the class, you'll have to find some other way of identifying which element you want.

Answer (score 0):

To make the element look up faster I'd suggest dropping the tag prefix since you mentioned you have a lot of links.

```
$('.class-name').prop('href');
```